# iOS 6 - Rate App links busted?

Tags: app-store, ios6, rate

i've put the iOS 6 GM on my iPhone 4 (not 4S),
and the 'rate it' buttons in my own app and others no longer do their thing.
instead it opens the app store w/ "cannot connect to itunes store".
regular app-links from safari work fine.

i'm using links of this form:

```
itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=<APP_ID>
```

for example, from safari on iOS 5.1, the link on this page works fine:
http://elenzil.com/scratch/appstore

but the same test w/ iOS 6 yields the problem i describe.

.. i have to say the App Store in general seems a bit buggy in the iOS 6 GM.
i'm seeing issues scrolling through the list of search results, mainly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We also ran into this, but it appears that Apple put in a fix this morning. No updates of iOS required.

Comment: interesting, thanks.
i don't see it behaving quite the same - looks like it now goes to the main info for the app rather than rate it.  .. but definitely an improvement !

Answer (score 1):

I'm using http and it works well in iOS6.

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=xxxxxxxxxx&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software

Just sharing what I use.

Comment: does that open safari before opening the app store ?

Comment: In iOS5 and below, yes. But in iOS6, it opens directly in the AppStore App!