# iPhone iOS 6 error when accessing company apps in App Store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

After updating my iPhone 4S to iOS 6, I have  noticed that in my apps, the following link, which works on older iOS does not work anymore, and displays an error: "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".

```
itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/<companynamestringhere>
```

Is anyone else experiencing this issue, and is there a fix available?

Comment: Looks like Apple is putting a fix in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426500/ios-6-rate-app-links-busted

Comment: The above link still does not work on iOS 6, but I found another link that works on iOS 6:  @"itms-apps://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=company\%20name\%20goes\%20here";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link works on iOS 6: @"itms-apps://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media‌​=software&term=company\%20name\%20goes\%20here";